# How to get all properties from a URI (jena, RDF, dbpedia)?

Tags: java, api, sparql, jena, dbpedia

Suppose the URI is `http://dbpedia.org/page/Ansungtangmyun` from the Named Graph `http://dbpedia.org`, within Data Space `dbpedia.org`

This resource includes the following properties:

- `dbo:abstract`
- `dbo:wikipageid`
- `dct:subject`
- `rdfs:comment`

etc.

What I have tried is to get one property at a time by exploring the graph. I am using Jena. To enhance the performance, I would like to ask whether there is a way/API to get all properties at once?

Comment: What's the matter with `select ?p ?o { <http://dbpedia.org/page/Ansungtangmyun> ?p ?o }` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing, I'd use the resource ID URI --

```
http://dbpedia.org/resource/Ansungtangmyun
```

-- instead of the HTML page URI --

```
http://dbpedia.org/page/Ansungtangmyun
```

-- which is to say, this query (and its [live results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=SELECT%20%3Fp%20%3Fo%0D%0AWHERE%20%0D%0A%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fresource%2FAnsungtangmyun%3E%20%20%3Fp%20%20%3Fo%0D%0A%20%20%7D&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&debug=on)) --

```
SELECT ?p ?o
WHERE 
  {
     <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Ansungtangmyun>  ?p  ?o
  }
```

You might also be interested in this (and its [live results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=DESCRIBE+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fresource%2FAnsungtangmyun%3E&format=text%2Fplain&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&debug=on)) --

```
DESCRIBE <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Ansungtangmyun>
```

Comment: The information retrieved by 'describe' is what I am looking at. I got the following items:
- dbr:Ansungtangmyun
- dct:subject
- dbc:South_Korean_brands dbc:Instant_noodle_brands
- dbo:wikiPageID
47897626
- dbo:wikiPageRevisionID
682686611
- dbo:wikiPageExternalLink
- n4:ansungtangmyun n10:
- rdfs:label
Ansungtangmyun
-rdfs:comment
Ansungtangmyun (Korean: 안성탕면) is a brand of ramyeon produced by Nongshim in South Korea since 1983, and is the third highest-selling brand of noodles in South Korea.
foaf:homepage
...
- wikipedia-en:Ansungtangmyun
- foaf:primaryTopic
...

Answer (score 1):

Try the following SPARQL query:

```
SELECT ?p
WHERE {
   <http://dbpedia.org/page/Ansungtangmyun> ?p ?o
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can directly get a whole graph having your property as subject by using a simple DESCRIBE query.

```
DESCRIBE <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Ansungtangmyun>
```